# UIAlertView without rounded corners

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am working with `UIAlertView` and I need remove corners from this.

Is any way to do it?

I am using `UIAlertView` + Blocks

Comment: You don't, you should not modify `UIAlertView` view or view hierarchy as clearly stated in the documentation: [`The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html)

Comment: @Unmerciful,its not possible.but alternate solution you can use custom UIAlertview like http://code4app.net/category/alertview.

Answer (score 0):

You can't by using UIAlertView. You need to use a custom object to achieve this. For example, you have [TTAlertView](https://github.com/twotoasters/TTAlertView) or a non intrusive alert view: [TSMessages](https://github.com/toursprung/TSMessages).